# pure numpy expression for selecting same-length subarrays with different starting indices from 3-D array

Tags: python, numpy

I have a 3-D `numpy` array (let's call it `a`) with shape `(74, 74, 4563)`, and I want to extract a length-`n` sub-array from each location in the first two dimensions. However, each of those sub-arrays starts in a different place, depending on the indices in the first two dimensions, `i` & `j`.

For example, if `n=1000`, I may want `a[0, 0, 0:1000]`, but also `a[0, 1, 2:1002]`, etc... I have a 2-d array (called `ix0`) which is a 2-d array that tells me where each sub-array starts for each `i`/`j` position. Finally, I am guaranteed that there will not be any "overflow"--that is, all the values in `ix0 + n` are smaller than the dimension-2 length of `a` (so we don't need to worry about asking for an index beyond the range that is present).

For example...

```
a = np.arange(74*74*4563).reshape(74, 74, 4563)
ix0 = np.arange(74*74).reshape(74,74)/2 + 50
a[:, :, ix0:ix0+n]
```

which produces

```
IndexError: failed to coerce slice entry of type numpy.ndarray to integer
```

Is there a way to do this without looping through all the `i`/`j` index combinations or creating a big mask array?

Comment: So, for indexing what do you have as input? I am assuming the indices for the first two dimensions and start,stop for the third dimension? Can you add a sample input case?

Comment: How does ix0 look like? If you want to identify two positions `i` and `j` AND the sub-array starting position, you'd need a 3D array as well, unless you do something with indices.

Comment: updated to provide a more explicit example attempt

Comment: Is it intentional that each row starts with last element+1 from the previous row for `ix0`?

Comment: No, it was just me coming up with a silly example. In reality, there's no i/j dependence of ix0--the values in ix0 are set elsewhere...

Comment: And you are selecting all elements along the first dimensions? I thought it said : `..." depending on the indices in the first two dimensions, i & j."`.

Comment: correction: there's no **functional** `i`/`j` dependence of ix0

Comment: I am still not sure on the intended output format. But, if you do `a[:, :, ix0[0]]`, `a[:, :, ix0[1]]` and so on, would you have your desired output? If so, are you looking to vectorize such an extraction?

Comment: The intended output format is a 74x74x1000 array (let's call it b), where b[0,0,:] = a[0,0,50:1050], b[0,1,:] = a[0,2,51:1051], b[1,0,:] = a[1,0,87:1087], etc... So if you look at a particular element of ix0, which we can call ix0[i,j], the corresponding array in b, which we call b[i,j,:], will have values equal to a[i,j,ix0[i,j]:ix0[i,j]+n]. And what I'm asking is how to do this in a vectorized manner, without resorting so a huge mask array or loops through all values of i and j.

Comment: I think I've worked what you want, but - a small test case where you resort the `loops through all values of i and j` would be desirable.  Note that to get there I started with a loop example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something along this line has been asked before, but for 2d.  I may try to look that up.

But here's quick example of what was going on in the 2d case

```
In [1463]: x=np.arange(12).reshape(3,4)
In [1464]: ix0=np.array([0,2,1])
In [1465]: N=2
```

We could iterate over each row of `x`, collecting the desired `N` length slice, and then join them into a list or array.  A more general problem varies the length of slices, in which case they can't be reassembled into an array.

```
In [1466]: [x[i,ix0[i]:ix0[i]+N] for i in range(3)]
Out[1466]: [array([0, 1]), array([6, 7]), array([ 9, 10])]
```

and then wrap that list in `np.array`.

An alternative is to concatenate the indexes first:

```
In [1467]: x[np.arange(3)[:,None], np.array([np.r_[ix0[i]:ix0[i]+N] for i in range(3)])]
Out[1467]: 
array([[ 0,  1],
       [ 6,  7],
       [ 9, 10]])
```

The last index array is:

```
In [1468]: np.array([np.r_[ix0[i]:ix0[i]+N] for i in range(3)])
Out[1468]: 
array([[0, 1],
       [2, 3],
       [1, 2]])
```

To apply to the 3d case we have two options.  One is reshape it to 2d, apply one of these strategies, and reshape back.  The other is to generalize the action I took to create these - that shouldn't be too hard, but will take some experimenting.

That last array shouldn't be hard to create with broadcasting.

```
In [1469]: ix0[:,None]+np.arange(N)
Out[1469]: 
array([[0, 1],
       [2, 3],
       [1, 2]])

In [1470]: x[np.arange(3)[:,None], ix0[:,None]+np.arange(N)]
Out[1470]: 
array([[ 0,  1],
       [ 6,  7],
       [ 9, 10]])
```

Now it should be even easier to generalize to 3d

```
In [1487]: X=np.arange(2*3*10).reshape(2,3,10)

In [1488]: ix0=np.arange(2*3).reshape(2,3)

In [1489]: ix0[...,None]+np.arange(N)
Out[1489]: 
array([[[0, 1],
        [1, 2],
        [2, 3]],

       [[3, 4],
        [4, 5],
        [5, 6]]])

In [1490]: I,J,_=np.ix_(range(2),range(3),range(N))

In [1491]: I.shape
Out[1491]: (2, 1, 1)

In [1492]: J.shape
Out[1492]: (1, 3, 1)

In [1493]: X[I, J, ix0[...,None]+np.arange(N)]
Out[1493]: 
array([[[ 0,  1],
        [11, 12],
        [22, 23]],

       [[33, 34],
        [44, 45],
        [55, 56]]])
```

I should make sure the values are right, but the shapes match, which in this sort of thing is 80% of work.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!