# Numpy: Broadcasting from submatrix

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

Given two 2D arrays:

```
A =[[1, 1, 2, 2],
    [1, 1, 2, 2],
    [3, 3, 4, 4],
    [3, 3, 4, 4]]

B =[[1, 2],
    [3, 4]]

A - B = [[ 0, -1,  1,  0],
         [-2, -3, -1, -2],
         [ 2,  1,  3,  2],
         [ 0, -1,  1,  0]]
```

B's shape is 2,2, A's is 4,4. I want to perform a broadcast subtraction of B over A: A - B.

I specifically want to use broadcasting as the array sizes I am dealing with are very large (8456,8456). I am hoping that broadcasting will provide a small performance optimization.

I've tried reshaping the arrays but with no luck, and am stumped. Scikit is not available to me to use.

Comment: What would the intended output be ?

Comment: It is possible to do this using only reshaping and axis swapping

Comment: @P.Camilleri As it turns out, we can just use reshaping :)

Answer (score 2):

You can expand `B` by tiling it twice in both dimensions:

```
print A - numpy.tile(B, (2, 2))
```

yields

```
[[ 0 -1  1  0]
 [-2 -3 -1 -2]
 [ 2  1  3  2]
 [ 0 -1  1  0]]
```

However for big matrices this may create a lot of overhead in RAM.

Alternatively you can [view `A` in blocks](http://scipy-cookbook.readthedocs.io/items/ViewsVsCopies.html) using Scikit Image's `skimage.util.view_as_blocks` and modify it in place

```
Atmp = skimage.util.view_as_blocks(A, block_shape=(2, 2))
Atmp -= B

print A
```

which will result, without needlessly repeating `B`

```
[[ 0 -1  1  0]
 [-2 -3 -1 -2]
 [ 2  1  3  2]
 [ 0 -1  1  0]]
```

Comment: Does tiling have to be used? I was hoping for the performance benefits of using broadcasting. I also don't have access to scikit.

Comment: Can't you just `pip install scikit-image`? Alternatively you could use [this function, that also does sliding windows](https://gist.github.com/nils-werner/9d321441006b112a4b116a8387c2280c).

Answer (score 2):

**Approach #1 :** Here's an approach using [`strides`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.strides.html) that uses the concept of [`views`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40367540/3293881) without making actual copies to then perform subtraction from `A`  and as such should be quite efficient -

```
m,n = B.strides
m1,n1 = A.shape
m2,n2 = B.shape
s1,s2 = m1//m2, n1//n2
strided = np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided         
out = A - strided(B,shape=(s1,m2,s2,n2),strides=(0,n2*n,0,n)).reshape(A.shape)
```

Sample run -

```
In [78]: A
Out[78]: 
array([[29, 53, 30, 25, 92, 10],
       [ 2, 20, 35, 87,  0,  9],
       [46, 30, 20, 62, 79, 63],
       [44,  9, 78, 33,  6, 40]])

In [79]: B
Out[79]: 
array([[35, 60],
       [21, 86]])

In [80]: m,n = B.strides
    ...: m1,n1 = A.shape
    ...: m2,n2 = B.shape
    ...: s1,s2 = m1//m2, n1//n2
    ...: strided = np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided
    ...: 

In [81]: # Replicated view
    ...: strided(B,shape=(s1,m2,s2,n2),strides=(0,n2*n,0,n)).reshape(A.shape)
Out[81]: 
array([[35, 60, 35, 60, 35, 60],
       [21, 86, 21, 86, 21, 86],
       [35, 60, 35, 60, 35, 60],
       [21, 86, 21, 86, 21, 86]])

In [82]: A - strided(B,shape=(s1,m2,s2,n2),strides=(0,n2*n,0,n)).reshape(A.shape)
Out[82]: 
array([[ -6,  -7,  -5, -35,  57, -50],
       [-19, -66,  14,   1, -21, -77],
       [ 11, -30, -15,   2,  44,   3],
       [ 23, -77,  57, -53, -15, -46]])
```

**Approach #2 :** We can just [`reshape`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html)  both `A` and `B` to `4D` shapes with `B` having two singleton dimensions along which its elements would be [`broadcasted`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) when subtracted from `4D` version of `A`. After subtraction, we reshape back to `2D` for final output. Thus, we would have an implementation, like so   -

```
m1,n1 = A.shape
m2,n2 = B.shape
out = (A.reshape(m1//m2,m2,n1//n2,n2) - B.reshape(1,m2,1,n2)).reshape(m1,n1)
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work if A has dimentions that are multiple of B's dimentions:

```
A - np.tile(B, (int(A.shape[0]/B.shape[0]), int(A.shape[1]/B.shape[1])))
```

And the result:

```
array([[ 0, -1,  1,  0],
       [-2, -3, -1, -2],
       [ 2,  1,  3,  2],
       [ 0, -1,  1,  0]])
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to tile, you can reshape A to extract `(2, 2)` blocks, and use broadcasting to substract B:

```
C = A.reshape(A.shape[0]//2, 2, A.shape[1]//2, 2).swapaxes(1, 2)
C - B
array([[[[ 0, -1],
     [-2, -3]],

    [[ 1,  0],
     [-1, -2]]],


   [[[ 2,  1],
     [ 0, -1]],

    [[ 3,  2],
     [ 1,  0]]]])
```

And then swap the axis back and reshape:

```
(C - B).swapaxes(1, 2).reshape(A.shape[0], A.shape[1])
```

This should be significantly faster, since C is a view on A, not a constructed array.