# Slice array into reversed overlapping subarrays

Tags: arrays, python-2.7, numpy, slice

How to effectively slice an array into overlapping subarrays, so that for

```
>>> N = 5
>>> L = 2  # could be any, less than N
>>> x = range(N)
```

the expected result is

```
[[1,0],[2,1],[3,2],[4,3]]
```

Here what I've tried:

```
>>> [ x[i:i-L:-1] for i in range(L-1,len(x)) ]
[[], [3, 2], [4, 3], [5, 4]]  # wrong

>>> [ x[i:i-L:-1] for i in range(L,len(x)) ]
[[2, 1], [3, 2], [4, 3]]  # wrong

>>> [ x[i:i-L if i-L >= 0 else None:-1] for i in range(L-1,len(x)) ]
[[1, 0], [2, 1], [3, 2], [4, 3]]  # correct
```

It produces the desired result, but is it the best way to achieve it?

Are there some numpy, itertools functions that may help?

Comment: So, is the input a list or NumPy array? Is the expected result a list or array? The title says `array`, whereas the sample is `range(N)` that creates a list.

Comment: Thanks, I expect it to be the one for which the better solution exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming the input as a NumPy array. So, if it's not already, we could have it as an array with [`np.asarray()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.asarray.html). Thus, we would start with : `x = np.asarray(input_list)` if the input is a list. So, with that as the setup let's try to solve the problem.

Here's an approach using [`strides`](http://www.scipy-lectures.org/advanced/advanced_numpy/#indexing-scheme-strides) that uses the concept of [`views`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40367540/3293881), which avoids making copies and as such must be pretty efficient -

```
L = 2 # Row length
strided = np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided
n = x.strides[0]
out = strided(x[L-1:],shape=(x.size-L+1,L),strides=(n,-n))
```

Sample runs -

```
In [85]: L = 2

In [86]: strided(x[L-1:],shape=(x.size-L+1,L),strides=(n,-n))
Out[86]: 
array([[1, 0],
       [2, 1],
       [3, 2],
       [4, 3]])

In [87]: L = 3

In [88]: strided(x[L-1:],shape=(x.size-L+1,L),strides=(n,-n))
Out[88]: 
array([[2, 1, 0],
       [3, 2, 1],
       [4, 3, 2]])

In [89]: L = 4

In [90]: strided(x[L-1:],shape=(x.size-L+1,L),strides=(n,-n))
Out[90]: 
array([[3, 2, 1, 0],
       [4, 3, 2, 1]])
```

Here's another approach using [`broadcasting`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) -

```
L = 2 # Row length
out = x[np.arange(x.size-L+1)[:,None] + np.arange(L-1,-1,-1)]
```

Comment: Where did `n` come from?

Answer (score 1):

You can use simple list comprehension

```
>>> [[x[i+1], x[i]] for i in range(len(x) - 1)]
[[1, 0], [2, 1], [3, 2], [4, 3]]
```

Or use [`itertools.izip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip):

```
>>> from itertools import izip
>>> [list(k) for k in izip(x[1:], x)]
[[1, 0], [2, 1], [3, 2], [4, 3]]
```

I see that you updated the question, so here's generic `itertools` way with use of [`itertools.izip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip), [`itertools.islice`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice) and [`itertools.imap`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.imap)

```
>>> res = imap(lambda i:islice(reversed(x), i, i+L), xrange(N-L,-1,-1))
>>> [list(e) for e in res]
[[1, 0], [2, 1], [3, 2], [4, 3]]
```

Or even pure generators:

```
>>> res = (reversed(x[i:i+L]) for i in xrange(N-L+1))
>>> [list(e) for e in res]
[[1, 0], [2, 1], [3, 2], [4, 3]]
```

Comment: Thanks, you provided simple and elegant solution for small subarrays. But what about the case of 10-element subarrays (also shifted by 1 element)? So that for `x = range(100)` the result will be `[[9,8,..,0],[10,9,..,1],..,[99,98,..,90]]`.

Comment: Something like [[x[i+n-1, i, -1] for i in range(len(x) - n + 1)] should work but i can't test it atm,will check when i get home

Answer (score 1):

Or with the regular zip (producing a list of tuples)

```
In [158]: x=list(range(5))
In [159]: x[1:],x[0:-1]
Out[159]: ([1, 2, 3, 4], [0, 1, 2, 3])
In [160]: list(zip(x[1:],x[0:-1]))
Out[160]: [(1, 0), (2, 1), (3, 2), (4, 3)]
```

or for lists

```
In [161]: [list(i) for i in zip(x[1:],x[0:-1])]
Out[161]: [[1, 0], [2, 1], [3, 2], [4, 3]]
```

This is use of zip is a kind of transpose.  `numpy` arrays also transposes easily:

```
In [167]: arr=np.array((x[1:],x[:-1]))
In [168]: arr
Out[168]: 
array([[1, 2, 3, 4],
       [0, 1, 2, 3]])
In [169]: arr.T.tolist()
Out[169]: [[1, 0], [2, 1], [3, 2], [4, 3]]
```

Note that I had to make two copies of the list.  Divakar's `stride_tricks` approach is the only way of creating overlapping 'windows' without copying.  It's a more advanced method.

For small lists, I'd suggest sticking with the list approaches.  There's overhead associated with creating arrays.