# Divide an Python array into small chunks starting at the end

Tags: python, numpy

I have a list of an evenly sampled signal. For the sake of discussion, assume that  the array can be obtained by the following python code

```
fs =2
np.arange(start=0, stop=360, step=fs)
```

In my perspective, the above code would correspond to a 90-second long signal. I would like to analyze small chunks of the last 10 seconds of the signal as follow:

```
 1. Iteration #1: array from the beginning to the end
 2. Iteration #2: array from the beginning to the (end -1 second) 
 3. Iteration #3: array from the beginning to the (end -2 seconds) 
 4. Iteration #4: array from the beginning to the (end -3 seconds) 
 5. Iteration #4: array from the beginning to the (end -3 seconds) 
    etc.... 
 5. Iteration #10: array from the beginning to the (end -10 second)
```

There are some convoluted ways I could maybe achieve this by using for loops and counters but I feel like this is overkill as I suspect this could be achieved by some simple array indexing methods as suggested by this [StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/312443/how-do-you-split-a-list-into-evenly-sized-chunks). Can someone point me in the right direction to get this done with an elegant code?

Comment: Seems like you want a regular for loop and `lst[:-i]`

Comment: There'll be a `np.indextricks.as_strided` to this problem

Comment: Using a stride of `1`, you can use - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40084931. Also relevant - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40345461

Comment: @cricket_007, your method seems the simplest. I am just yet to figure out how to calculate the index i for `lst[:-i]`

Comment: Start with `for i in range(10)` to see if it does what you want

Comment: One issue is identifying the chunks, the other is what do you want to do with them?  If the chunks are all the same length they can be stacked into a 2d array.  But if they differ in length (beginning to different ends), they probably have to handled individually.  Ragged arrays don't stack.